# Is it possible to use a recurring fee for a Windows Store App

Tags: win-universal-app

I plan to publish an Windows Universal application to the Window Store. Do you think it's possible to create a recurring fee for this app ?

This way, the users will pay a small fee each month versus a one time fee at purchase time.

Thanks,
Julien

Answer (score 0):

you can sell `Consumable` IAP, check each time user by it (once a month ?) and active features accordingly.

Comment: Hi thang, I was thinking more about something like this : http://betanews.com/2015/04/29/windows-10-store-subscriptions/

Answer (score 0):

If you adding licensing in your application you are using

[LicenseInformation class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br225157)

This class has [ExpirationDate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.licenseinformation.expirationdate) property - that means date when app license expired

Usualy it is used for making Trial period, but you can try to combine it with [app purchase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.store.currentapp.requestapppurchaseasync.aspx) anf licence will be sold every time for some period only